# SyntaxError: Document.evaluate: The expression is not a legal expression

Tags: python, xml, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am being given the following error for my XPath definition:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression ..... is invalid: SyntaxError: Document.evaluate: The expression is not a legal expression

The expression is defined below:

```
total_games = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="mb5"]/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[@data-idx and not @class="totals_row fw-bold ttu Table__TR Table__TR--sm Table__even"]')
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
not @class="totals_row fw-bold ttu Table__TR Table__TR--sm Table__even"
```

should be

```
not(@class="totals_row fw-bold ttu Table__TR Table__TR--sm Table__even")
```